# I cannot find elements on a Page using selenium

Tags: iframe, webdriver

This is the code I have written for logging in

```
getDriver().switchTo().frame("gsft_main");
typeInto(userNameInput, user);
typeInto(passwordInput, pass);
```

When I try to access the login input fields, the element that's supposed to be enabled does not get enabled. If I try to switch to the frame using `getDriver().switchTo().frame("gsft_main");`, I get no frame element found by name or id `gsft_main`.

```
https://bpfaudev.service-now.com/csm/?id=csm_login ----> HTML
```